# Scan for key press in Console without pausing it

Tags: c#, windows, dll, console

I have this problem. I have while loop for drawing text in console and I want to make it interactive. I have two if statements which contains condition for actual key.
So if I press 'W' it will do something, but that wont work. I have two projects, engine.dll and testApp for testing. Heres the code:

```
 while (true)
            {
                game g = new game();
                g.Draw(cHP, mHP, name,posX,posY,blip);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                Console.CursorVisible = false;
                ConsoleKeyInfo cki = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
                //if (Console.KeyAvailable) { Console.CursorVisible = true; break; }
                if (cki.KeyChar == 'w') MoveY(1); // Here it is
                if (cki.KeyChar == 's') MoveY(-1); // and here
            }
```

Comment: Don't use thread.sleep for a start, put the readkey on a background worker and then do something when it finishes (if this would even work)

Comment: What's wrong with `Console.KeyAvailable` ?

Comment: @zmbq - Never seen that before, very nice

Comment: As I know, Console.KeyAvailable just control just whether any key was clicked or not. Its Boolean, which I dont need to use.

Comment: Not sure what your design is, but most likely the `game g = new game();` line should be **BEFORE** the `while` loop....

Comment: Yes, I know, but I need it like it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want in the final version but a fix to your existing code would be this

```
 Console.CursorVisible = false;
 while(true)
 {
       game g = new game();
       g.Draw(cHP, mHP, name,posX,posY,blip);
       Thread.Sleep(50); //might not be required depending
                         //on what you want to do

       var cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
       if (cki.KeyChar == 'w') MoveY(1);// Here it is
       if (cki.KeyChar == 's') MoveY(-1); // and here
 }
```